# Overflow list not working in IE7

Tags: html, css

I have an accordion that is not working in some versions of Internet Explorer. 
See it at http://autofile.co.nz/ - is the code compatible or will I have to hide it for certain versions of IE?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include code in your question and an example on a site such as http://jsfiddle.net/ if possible or appropriate. If you start changing the code on your site we will have no idea where you started. Don't include the whole page. Just what is not performing as exprectd.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for it to break in IE7 is that it is throwing exception for 'meanmenu' for

```
jQuery('menubar nav').meanmenu();
```

This is not working on IE8 as well.